# how can I manipulate key with for loops to update dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, key

I am trying to put a list into a dictionary and count the number of occurrences of each word in the list. The only problem I don't understand is when I use the update function, it takes x as a dictionary key, when I want x to be the x value of list_ . I am new to python so any advice is appreciated. Thanks

```
list_ = ["hello", "there", "friend", "hello"]
d = {}
for x in list_:
    d.update(x = list_.count(x))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object if you want a simple way of converting a list of items to a dictionary which contains a mapping of `list_entry: number_of_occurences` .

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> words = ['hello', 'there', 'friend', 'hello']
>>> c = Counter(words)

>>> print(c)
Counter({'hello': 2, 'there': 1, 'friend': 1})

>>> print(dict(c))
{'there': 1, 'hello': 2, 'friend': 1}
```

Comment: Wow didn't know you can do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

An option would be using dictionary comprehension with [`list.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) like this:

```
list_ = ["hello", "there", "friend", "hello"]
d = {item: list_.count(item) for item in list_}
```

**Output:**

```
>>> d
{'hello': 2, 'there': 1, 'friend': 1}
```

But the best option should be [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) used in @AK47's solution.